# remove white background from dragImage

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop, drag

I've a draggable element and whenever I drag that from a dark background, it shows the white outline. Is there a way or hack to remove it completely? I want to make it transparent

Here's how it looks like:

[image]

**Here's my code:**

```
document.addEventListener("dragstart", (e) => {
    const ghost = document.createElement("div");

    // I've used Tailwind for styling...
    ghost.className = "bg-indigo-500 h-[30px] w-[100px] drop-shadow-md";
    document.body.appendChild(ghost);

    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(ghost, 0, 0);
  });
```

**Update:**

This is happening only on Chrome Linux, On windows there are no white outlines as such.

Comment: Abhay it would be great if you can post css of that draggable element. I think the elemet has outline or border itself.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its an issue with the outline. See if setting the CSS *outline* property to *none*. In tailwind, I believe you can you do it using *outline-0*. Give it a go!

Answer (score 0):

You can override CSS while isDragging is true (depends which dnd lib you're using, if you wrote is yourself just add it). Add Tailwind 'outline-none'.
If you want to 'hack it you can use !important. It is possible that you will have to use it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this hack:
create a `span` with the same width and height as the box.

Give it `display: none;` or `visibility: hidden;` based on convenience.

While you are dragging, make it visible.